# Unity AndroidJNI resolves classes but not methods

Tags: java, c#, unity-game-engine, jna

I am trying to interface with native Android methods from C# in Unity using AndroidJNI, however I can only resolve classes, not methods.

I have also used the 'simpler variants', meaning AndroidJavaClass interface, but the error says its trying to resolve the methods from java.lang.Object, therefore I moved onto using AndroidJNI, but am stuck resolving the methods.

I have the following java method 

    `public static String getParamsString2() {
        return "asd";
    }`

and the following c# code trying to resolve the method id

```
 AndroidJNI.GetStaticMethodID(activityClass, "getParamsString2", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
```

I have verified from the decompiler that the signature is correct, however I end up receiving the following error

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no static method "Lfi/matalamaki/plugin/UnityPlayerActivity;.getParamsString2()Ljava/lang/String;
```

When I decompile the class there actually is the class which contains the method

```
 public static getParamsString2() { //()Ljava/lang/String;
     L1 {
         ldc "asd" (java.lang.String)
         areturn
     }
 }
```

The class is also correct, `fi/matalamaki/plugin/UnityPlayerActivity`

when using the AndroidJavaClass interface with code

```
    string referrer3 = new AndroidJavaClass("fi.matalamaki.plugin.UnityPlayerActivity").CallStatic<string>("getParamsString2", new object[0]);
```

I get the following error `AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no static method with name='getParamsString2' signature='()Ljava/lang/String;' in class Ljava.lang.Object;
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no static method with name='getParamsString2' signature='()Ljava/lang/String;' in class Ljava.lang.Object;`

which seems to indicate that its trying to resolve the method from java.lang.Object instead of my own class..

I've tried different parameter and return type combinations but no luck..

I've also verified the built APK dex by decompiling it..

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it was Proguard that by minifying or by obfuscating removed the method or renamed it. I have no idea how after verifying I saw the method there, but maybe I wasn't paying enough attention, and it had its name changed or so.

After adding a proguard exclusion on my package and its fields and methods the problem is now solved.